# How to design table so that copied text from pdf in sorted by rows in text file?

Tags: tables, xetex, kile

I have a simple table with text:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{2pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \emph{#3} & \emph{#4} \\
    \end{tabular*}
  \vspace{-1pt}
}

\begin{document}  

    \resumeSubheading
      {row 0 column 0}{row 0 column 1}
      {row 1 column 0}{row 1 column 1}

\end{document}
```

However, when I copy text from the resulting `pdf` file to a notepad, the text is sorted by columns:

```
row 0 column 0
row 1 column 0
row 0 column 1
row 1 column 1
```

**How to create pdf so that copied text is sorted by rows?**

Comment: The sorting issue may be caused by the pdf viewer you employ. Which pdf viewer do you employ? I happen to use Acrobat; when I copy and paste the tabular material to a text file, the ordering of the rows is preserved just fine. This is true both for a `tabular*` environment, as in your code, and for a `tabular` environment.

Comment: Just to confirm that All 'swell with SumatraPDF **row 0 column 0 row 0 column 1** *row 1 column 0 row 1 column 1*

Comment: It is really dependent on the pdf viewer as I received this format with both `evince` and `okular`, compared to copied text from `foxit` reader whose rows were not separated: `row 0 column 0row 0 column 1\n row 1 column 0row 1 column 1`.